# Transactions in Grails

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-orm

In several domain class I have a property `createdBy` with class `User`. If I delete a user I want to alter all domain objects to use a default user for this property.

I want to do this by transactions (alter all or do nothing). 
How do I do this with grails transactions?

Comment: You mean that "createdBy" in all the tables are foreign keyed and when the user has been deleted, you want to change the value to a default user? That would not be such a great idea as it may result in multiple tables and rows updates, the better approaches would be just marking the user as deleted or don't make the field FK and when you delete the user, put him in a legacy user table for future ref..

Comment: I usually create a service and set it to transactional, this link would explain all there is to it: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As -marko- already commented you could do this by implementing a service. Another approach could be to use the 'beforeDelete' event. When using the beforeDelete make sure you use another hibernate Session.

```
User.withNewSession { 
     // your code here 
}
```